# Which interceptor is responsible to map for struts.xml configuration file in Struts2

Tags: struts2

How Struts2 controller check, we need to check our action mapping in Struts.xml file. Which Interceptor check, we need to search for our action in Struts.xml?

I mean to say, why we need to provide its name as Struts.xml? Beacuse suppose if we are gonna change its name, then we have to override cofig init-param. But for this we need to provide Struts-default.xml in param-value as first parameter. then only, I will be able to change struts.xml name.

For Example:-

```
<init-param>
<param-name>config</param-name>
<param-value>struts-default.xml,test.xml</param-vale>
</init-param>
```

So I want to ask why it don't work without struts-default.xml.

Comment: When you use struts tags the action is checked in the dev mode at the rendering phase.

Comment: All the pre requisite results,beans and interceptors for your configuration to work is defined in struts-default.xml.Without that your configuration wont work. So inorder to make your custom configuration file to work, you need to instruct the bootstrap servlet/filter default file as well. Or you could copy all the contents from struts-default.xml into your test.xml, that would also work same.